# \lstlisting in \multicolumn in a macro

Tags: tables, macros, listings

I want to create a macro for putting a multiline JSON code in a multicolumn row in a tabular environment...

```
\newcommand{\apiMethodRequest}[1]{
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\cellcolor{DsnGreen}{Request}} \\ \hline                                          
Example body& \multicolumn{4}{l}{
        \begin{lstlisting}[language=json]
            \hspace{0pt}#1
        \end{lstlisting}
    } \\
}
```

...and use it in a following manner:

```
\apiMethodRequest{
 \{"id":"1",
   "actions":["call", "sms","call"]
 \}
}
```

This, however, yields this error:

```
Forbidden control sequence found while scanning definition of  \lst@temp. ...d":"1","actions":["call", "sms","call"]\}}
```

Without `lstlisting` it works fine, but this results in a lack of line breaks. Could you please tell me where's my mistake?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can't put an environment like`lstlisting` into an another command argument, because `lstlisting` uses `verbatim` mode which isn't allowed for command arguments

Comment: Please post documents, not just fragments only and try to drop the `tabular` approach

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thanks for your answer. Is there a possibility to put explicit multicolumn line breaks in macro argument (like a JSON from the example)?

Comment: The problem is not `\multicolumn`, it's the verbatim stuff. Any macro will break then